# What is the relation between the torque generated by the flagellar motor and the torque acted on the flagellar and cell body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, biophysics

[image]

I was reading a lecture slide on modeling the motion of E. Coli and came into this set of equations. The equations are given assuming the bacterium is in constant straight motion so no net force and torque. I am confused and have some questions. (All variables are written as vectors)

1. Because there are no net torques, shouldn't $$ \Gamma_f + \Gamma_{body} + \Gamma_m = 0 $$ where m means motor?

Why it didn't include the torque generated by the motor?

2. To make it easier, assuming only 1 motor so N = 1. How do we get $$\Gamma_f - \Gamma_{body} = \Gamma_m$$ What kind of law is this?